# ValidateCredentials() - Security Concerns

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm hoping all of you .NET devs out there can help me with this dilemma. I currently manage an ASP.NET intranet site at my company. To authenticate our users with Active Directory, we have code similar to the following:

```
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, string name, string user, string password) {

  bool credsOK = pc.ValidateCredentials(string user, string password);

  //Check if the creds come back valid
  if(credsOK) {

      //Do Stuff
  }
}
```

My concern is that someone with access to the code could potentially set a breakpoint at the if statement after the call to ValidateCredentials, add a watch on the password variable, and thus be able to see the user's password in plain text, which to me is dangerous and insecure, especially in a domain context.

So a couple of questions:

**1) Why does ValidateCredentials take credentials as plain strings vs. more secure data types?**

**2) What are some best practice ways I could pursue authenticating the user against AD using their credentials, without using ValidateCredentials()?**

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-rk15000

Comment: **vs. more secure data types** - what do you believe are those *more secure* types? If someone manages to start a debugging session *inside* your server, do you really believe reading passwords is the most dangerous thing that could happen?

Comment: Maybe breakpoint is not the only case rk has in mind. Someone with access to the code could add logging, etc to log the data. Of course, it doesn't change the fact, if someone has access to the code, they could put just about anything in there they want... :)

Comment: @Frederico Dipuma - Thanks for your question, but please save the sarcasm. I can't rule out the possibility that one of our own devs might attach to a process that someone else could be using accidentally, etc. More secure data types would be something akin to .NET SecureString (which in and of itself isn't very secure but better than a plain old string)...

Answer (score 0):

My thinking on this, if someone has access to the source code and put breakpoints for harvesting passwords, there is probably bigger concerns to worry about.  They are after all going to need to be in a position to be able to attach remote debuggers to your production server(s).

To answer your question though.  You will probably need to go down the route of separate sign-in services that would isolate the authentication form your application using some SSO tool like ADFS maybe.  However based on the example you've given it's unclear how much of an impact that is going to have

Comment: I agree that if someone had access to the server to actually do this, that would be a bigger problem. I just didn't know if this was THE best practices way of validating credentials in .NET, and if a more secure method existed. In my research I have not been able to find a direct replacement for this method.

Comment: Well, the alternative really is using some external service for authentication.  I don't know anything about your environment/requirements though so can't really go much further than that.  Anything in your code base is going to be just as visible.  We have to assume if someone can get to the ValidateCredentials call in your code, they will be able to see everything else too, at some stage the password is going to have to be plain text before any sort of secure transformation takes place